# Not able to mock passive location provider in android

Tags: android, location

Here is my code :

```
public class MockLocationHelper {

    private String providerName ;
    private Context context;
    private LocationManager locationManager ;

    MockLocationHelper(String providerName, Context context){
        this.providerName = providerName;
        this.context = context;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        try {
            locationManager.addTestProvider(providerName, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, 1, 2);
            locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, true);
        }catch(SecurityException e){
            Log.d(TAG, "SecurityException : MockLocationHelper()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException : MockLocationHelper()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void startMocking(String latitude, String longitude) {

        Location location = new Location(providerName);
        location.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latitude));
        location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(longitude));
        location.setAltitude(0);
        location.setAccuracy(2);
        location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(System.nanoTime());

        try {
            locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, location);
        }catch(SecurityException e){
            Log.d(TAG, "SecurityException : startMocking()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException : startMocking()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopMocking(){

        try{
            locationManager.removeTestProvider(providerName);
        }catch(SecurityException e){
            Log.d(TAG, "SecurityException : stopMocking()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException : stopMocking()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is onCreate() function :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           final EditText latitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
           final EditText longitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.longitude);

           Location location = new Location(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
location.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latitude.getText().toString()));
location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(longitude.getText().toString()))

    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
              MockLocationHelper  mockLocationHelper = new MockLocationHelper(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, this);
        mockLocationHelper.startMocking(latitude.getText().toString(), longitude.getText().toString());
            mockLocationHelper.stopMocking();

            latitude.setText("");
            longitude.setText("");
        }
```

When this code is run, it gives **IllegalAregumentException : "passive" provider unknown.** This code works fine if we replace provider with GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Manifest permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

Mock option is enable in developer console and I am running app on Kitkat. Why I am getting this exception and How should I mock passive locations ?

Comment: can you post your entire error

Answer (score 1):

You need to call addTestProvider first. But be aware that you cannot Mock passive provider, you must mock NETWORK or GPS ones.

See [this link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.android.server.location.MockProvider) for details on how addTestProvider behaves

```
    public void test1_TestCaseFoo()
    {
       Location location = new Location("network");
       location.setLatitude(-15.83554363);
       location.setLongitude(-48.01770782);
       location.setTime(new Date().getTime());
       location.setAccuracy(100.0f);
       location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(System.nanoTime());

       LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       locationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
       locationManager.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
       locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
       locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, location);

       locationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
       locationManager.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
       locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, true);
       locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, location);


       mActivity = getActivity();
       ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Android manifest file should be like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

You can find more details here **[Request User Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Permission)** And use your java code instead of : `Location lastKnow =  locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);` as below

```
try {
    Location lastKnow1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
    Location lastKnow2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Location lastKnow3 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(lastKnow1 != null){
       --- your code ---
    } if(lastKnow2 != null){
       --- your code ---
    } if(lastKnow3 != null){
       --- your code ---
    } else {
       --- Toast ---
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

By using above code you will never face exception problems. ** HAPPY CODING **